# MySQL C++ connector loop

Tags: c++, exception

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <mysql_driver.h>
#include <mysql_error.h>

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace sql;
using namespace mysql;
int main()
{
 Connection* con = nullptr;
 MySQL_Driver *driver = get_mysql_driver_instance();
 const SQLString server = "server.de";
 const SQLString user = "userName";
 const SQLString password = "password";

 while (1)
 {
  try {
   con = driver->connect(server, user, password);
  }
  catch (SQLException e) {
   printf("Fehler SQL Connect: %s \n", e.getSQLStateCStr());
   delete driver;
  }
  catch (...) {
   cerr << "Fehler SQL Connnect" << endl;
  }
  if (con)
  {
   con->close();
   delete con;
  }
  boost::detail::Sleep(5000);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I wrote this code and hoped it would run in an endless loop even, if the connect statement failed.
What happens is:
After the first time the connect failes it goes to the first catch statement and writes "Fehler SQL Connect: HY000" as I expect.
The next time the connect failes the program breakes and in VS2017 I see 'te923021119.exe has triggered a breakpoint'
Why doesn't the program try to connect endlessly?
ncb

Comment: You delete `driver` in your exception handler. In the next iteration the pointer is invalid.

Comment: @M.Spiller Don't answer in the comments section

Comment: Please edit the title. This has nothing to do with exception handling in a loop. It has to do with using the MySQL C++ connector properly.

Answer (score 1):

In your exception handled you call  `delete driver;` 
This call destroys the driver object. It is not clear if it the right thing to do - as it is not clear if `get_mysql_driver_instance()` gives you the ownership of a dynamically allocated object with `new`.
But regardless - in the next iteration your program attempts to use `driver` - which has been destroyed.
So - methinks don't call `delete driver;`. Better yet - use smart pointers to communicate ownership semantic clearly. std::unique_ptr may be a good option.

Comment: For the record: **no, it is not the right thing to do**. [_"But do not explicitly free driver, the connector object. Connector/C++ takes care of freeing that."_.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-connecting.html)

Comment: your right, deleting the "delete driver" fixes the problem.